# viewing stock market transactions

Tags: stocks, law, tracking

What I would like to know how to keep on eye on things like sale of a certain stock?, who is buying what stock?, what stocks are certain people buying?

Is it legal to have access to these sorts of things?

Comment: Yes it is perfectly legal, but the details of such information aren't shared with all. I would be surprised to find if any of the brokers/exchanges will be willing to share such information in detail.

Comment: Are you interested in individual people or just total volume of buys and sells in particular stocks?

Comment: Individual people

Answer (score 1):

You can't track what individuals are buying/selling, but you can track what mutual fund portfolio managers are buying/selling.  They report their holdings every 3 months.

Answer (score 1):

Information on who is buying and selling is confidential, so you will not find it anywhere.  The exceptions are insider executives, who have to disclose certain trades to the SEC.  That's it.

Large institutions (and mutual funds) periodically report their equity holdings, but that is very different from reporting their trades.